# How to disable python imagecodecs perf report?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I'm using `imagecodecs` to read multiple JXR files, but each call of `jpegxr_decode()` prints a large amount of unnecessary garbage:

```
***************************************************************************
* Perf Report
***************************************************************************

Image Width = 5120, Height = 1440, total MegaPixels = 7.4 MP
m_ptEncDecPerf (excl I/O): 75.000 milliseconds, 98.304001 MP/sec
   *** WARNING: 500 time intervals were measured as zero. This perf timer has insufficient precision!

m_ptEndToEndPerf (incl I/O): 76.000 milliseconds, 97.010529 MP/sec
```

Is there a way to disable this? `warnings.simplefilter("ignore")` has no effect. The platform is Windows 11 with Anaconda, installed with `conda install -c conda-forge imagecodecs`.

Comment: Please specify your platform and how imagecodecs was installed. The messages are emitted by the `jxrlib` library. It has to be compiled with the `DISABLE_PERF_MEASUREMENT` flag.

Answer (score 1):

The messages are printed by the `jxrlib` library. The library has to be compiled with the `DISABLE_PERF_MEASUREMENT` flag to disable the messages.

[Conda-forge does not use that flag when building `jxrlib` on Windows](https://github.com/conda-forge/jxrlib-feedstock/blob/main/recipe/bld.bat). I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/conda-forge/jxrlib-feedstock/pull/5).

To fix the issue, install [imagecodecs from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/), which includes a properly build `jxrlib` library and additional codecs missing from the conda-forge builds.